# Graphics are too slow when using drawRect

Tags: java, performance, awt, drawrect

I'm making a drawing board, and I have a few questions.

1. Whenever I try to draw on it, it doesn't automatically update. Ad I usually have to resize the screen for it to update.
2. How can I do something like a mouseDragged function, in which i can continually get the x and y coords?

Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.geom.*;
class griddedInput extends JComponent implements MouseListener
{
    int SIZE = 10;
    int scSize = 300;
    int sSize = scSize/SIZE;
    boolean [][] grid = new boolean[sSize][sSize];
    public griddedInput(boolean grid[][])
    {
        grid=grid;
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(scSize,scSize));
        addMouseListener(this);
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        int x, y;
        for(y = 0; y < sSize; y ++) {
            for(x = 0; x < sSize; x ++) {
                if(grid[y][x])
                    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                else
                    g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                g2.fillRect((x * SIZE), (y * SIZE), sSize, sSize);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        int squareX = (int)e.getX() / SIZE;
        int squareY = (int)e.getY() / SIZE;
        grid[squareY][squareX] = !grid[squareY][squareX];
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to call `repaint()` on the drawing component any time you want to suggest to the JVM that it be painted -- most likely in your MouseListener method(s).

e.g.,

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    int squareX = (int)e.getX() / SIZE;
    int squareY = (int)e.getY() / SIZE;
    grid[squareY][squareX] = !grid[squareY][squareX];
    repaint();
}
```

To speed up repainting, you can also call the overload method that allows you to repaint a select rectangle of your GUI, but I'll bet that you don't need to do that for this GUI.

You'll also want to be a little less "creative" with your code indentation if you want others to better be able to understand it and help you.

**Edit**
Regarding:

> 2.How can I do something like a mouseDragged function, in which i can continually get the x and y coords?

Also add a MouseMotionListener. It can be the same class, and in fact usually I use an anonymous inner class for this, one that extends MouseAdapter, and one whose single instance I use for both MouseListener and MouseMotionListener. I have examples of using this in several posts in this very forum.

Comment: @user1377835: your indents are all over the place making it hard for us to logically follow your code. If your code is easier to read with use of standard regular indentation, we'll be able to help you better, meaning you'll get better quicker answers here. And we'll appreciate your efforts to make it easier for us.

Comment: What about something like a mousedrag listener. And thanks, you're advice really helped!

Comment: Thank you! And one more question...when I click on the sides, 3 boxes activate in a row or column. How do I fix this?

Comment: @user1377835: please first fix your code so that I can better understand it. Use 3 spaces for each indentation, since this works better with the forum software.

Answer (score 1):

I would structure this a bit differently:

```
private BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
private Graphics2D big = bi.createGraphics();

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, this);
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    int squareX = (int)e.getX() / SIZE;
    int squareY = (int)e.getY() / SIZE;
    boolean b = !grid[squareY][squareX];
    grid[squareY][squareX] = b;
    if(b)
        big.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    else
        big.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    big.fillRect((x * SIZE), (y * SIZE), sSize, sSize);
    repaint();
}
```

The `mouseClicked` performs a single `fillRect` and the `paintComponent` a single `drawImage`. Compare this with the original code that performs **900** `fillRects` on every repaint.

You will also need to detect changes to the size and recreate the `BufferedImage` at that time.